# Increase token expiry time with gdrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am currently trying to upload files automatically to Google Drive. I used their default example from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). But, this usually downloads a token, which is after we manually login to browser and then authenticate. Also, this has expiry time too. I am actually trying to automate the process, so is there a way to set the expiry to "never expire"? If not, how can i at least increase the expiry time to 12 hours, or 24 hours, etc.?

Comment: If you're using a client library, they usually will handle the token refresh, if your original request was for a refreshable token. You should include in your question the relevant code.

Comment: @tehhowch, yeah...i just checked...it was updating automatically. Can you post this as answer. I will accept it. Thank you very much